# Can a Batch file report column number of found string?

Tags: string, batch-file, find

I have large fixed length text files, columns that are separated with two spaces.
What I would really like to do is have a batch file report the beginning and ending column number for each column of data based on the first & last line in text file.

The first and last line in text file should be the same (same column bytes) and if not report so.
Sometimes there is an extra carriage return for the last line so I am sure that will have to be checked for and erased then analyze last line to compare against first line.

The lines could contain the following  [aA,zZ], [0-9], =, ^, ?, \, /, %, ;

```
0000000000  00000  000000000=000000000  KM000000
```

The above COULD report (2 spaces being the separator)
10, 2, 5, 2, 19, 2, 8

Or report range of each column (2 spaces being the separator) 
1-10,11-12,13-17,18-36,37-38,39-46

I am unsure if this is even possible or where to even start.
I understand showing a sample of code is wanted and preferred but I am just unsure how to go about it from the start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your expected result is wrong - you are missing the position of one of the delimiters. The correct result is `1-10,11-12,13-17,18-19,20-38,39-40,41-48`. But I don't understand why you want the position of the delimiters, since they don't contain data. This could get really confusing if a data column has a length of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processor](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) can be a big help. It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Extensive documentation is available by running `jrepl /?` from the command line. You may want to use `jrepl /? | more` to get help one screen at a time. But my console is configured with a large output buffer, so I can scroll up to see prior output, so I don't need MORE.

I believe the following does pretty much what you want. It analyzes the first and last lines of the specified text file and prints out a comma delimited list of the column offsets within each line. If it detects an invalid character or something other than two spaces between each column then it includes ERROR in the output. I've modified the output to exclude the position of the two space delimiters.

The following command should be run from the command line, assuming you have JREPL.BAT in a folder that is included within your PATH.

```
jrepl "([a-zA-Z0-9=^?\\/%;]+)(?:  )?|.+" "','+($off+1)+'-'+($off+$2.length)|' ERROR'" /c /j /t "|" /jbegln "skip=(ln!=1&&ln!=cnt)" /jendln "$txt=skip?false:$txt.slice(1)" /f test.txt
```

Here is the output for your sample text file:

```
1-10,13-17,20-38,41-48
1-10,13-17,20-38,41-48
```

If you put the command within a batch script, then you should use CALL JREPL, in which case the percents need to be double escaped.

```
call jrepl "([a-zA-Z0-9=^?\\/%%%%;]+)(?:  )?|.+" "','+($off+1)+'-'+($off+$2.length)|' ERROR'" /c /j /t "|" /jbegln "skip=(ln!=1&&ln!=cnt)" /jendln "$txt=skip?false:$txt.slice(1)" /f test.txt
```

**How it works**

`/f "test.txt"` specifies the source file, in this case "test.txt"

`/c` counts the number of lines in the file and stores the value in variable `cnt`.

`/jbegln ...` disables search and replace if the current line is 1 or cnt by setting `skip` to true.

`/jendln ...` disables print out of the current line if `skip` is true, otherwise strips the initial comma from the output.

`/j` treats the replacement string as JScript code.

`/t "|"` treats the search and replace strings as like sized lists of expressions, delimited by `|`. The first replacement expression is used with the first search expression, and the second replacement expression is used with the second search expression. The searches are processed from left to right, so the second expression is only tested if the first one failed to match.

The first argument is the list of search expressions.

The second argument is the list of replacement expressions.

Search 1: Looks for a valid column with one or more valid characters, optionally followed by exactly two spaces. Note that the first search expression is assigned $1, so the captured expression in parentheses (the actual data column) becomes $2 instead of $1.

Replacement 1: a comma, followed by the offset of the match (0 based) + 1, followed by a dash, followed by the match offset + the length of the captured expression.

Search 2: Looks for a string of any characters.

Replacement 2: the " ERROR" string.

Comment: Thank you for the response and you have gone above and beyond already but when I run your code without touching it against a test.txt file in the same directory as jrepl.bat and your command in a batch file... the following error happens with regex expression..
"JScript runtime error in Search regular expression: Expected ']' in regular expression"

Comment: SORRY I am and idiot!  I copied your first line of code rather than the batch code you put second.  I did this KNOWING you said that and totally meant to copy the stupid batch code.   Anyway I am sorry and this fully answered my question... I appreciate it VERY much!  Thank you

Comment: Did you say this is suppose to error if something doesn't match?  I am not complaining, this answer is working fine for what I was wanting, but if an error is supposed to happen when the first line does not match the last line, or if any line is different, it doesn't.  It currently will tell you the byte count for the first and the last.  Was unsure if it is suppose to ERROR or not.  Anyway thank you again.

Comment: Any way to put the 2 results to a variable?  Then I could compare %var1% = %var2%  ... not sure how to get the result back to original batch file.

Comment: I see the error report comes when the 2 space separators are not there... Unfortunately there are times when the text files have a space in the columns.   So if there is 0000 0000 it reports error.  I will look at regex portion and see if I can add it.